# How to add same name menu items in joomla menu

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

On my Homepage I have 2 menus, for the top `main menu` initial element is "HOME". Now on my `footer menu` I wanted to start with the same menu item so i checked "Main Menu" from administrator and here it is mentioned like this->

```
HOME (Alias: home)
Articles » Featured Articles
```

So i created a new Featured article as "home" and it is successfully created. Now when attaching this to my footer menu I am getting this error -

```
Warning: Save failed with the following error: Another menu item has the same alias in Root. Root is the top level parent
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong, and how do I create Home menu item that do the same stuff, i.e on click return to the main site(`http://localhost/mysite`) currently main menu item is doing that and I want to do the same from the footer menu Home item as well but it is not creating successfully :( Help me plz

PS- Even "`About Us`" article that is on my `main menu` is not including at my `footer menu` with the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use same menu item into multiple places like main-menu and footer. So you can use menu type called **Menu Item Alias**. To do this, create a new menu then select the menu type to **Menu Item Alias** as shown below:

**Joomla 2.5**

[image]

**Joomla 3.0**

[image]

Expand system link tab and select **menu item alias**

[image]

Then add the name you want and then from right side select the menu item that you want to show on this menu item like shown here:

**Joomla 2.5**

[image]

**Joomla 3.0**

[image]

Then save it. Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thx for the reply..actually this setting I am unable to locate in New Joomla 3.0 version :(

Comment: @swapnesh This method is also available Joomla 3.0. To do this click on select menu type and then under the systemlinks you found Menu Item Alias.